# JavaScript - Using "this" with chained promises

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise

I am writing some Node code with ES6. In my code, I have a class, that looks like the following. Please note, this is a basic example intended to isolate and show the problem.

```
class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    this.id = uuid();
    this.number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
  }

  process() {
    this.validateNumber()
      .then(this.generateImage)
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
      })
    ;
  }

  validateNumber() {
    let self = this;
    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      // do stuff with self.number
      resolve({});
    });
  }

  generateImage() {
    console.log(this);
    // the above prints "undefined" in the console window
    // how do I get this.number again?

  }
}
```

In this class, you'll notice that I generate a random number in my constructor. I want that number to be usable throughout the methods in my class. However, since I have one method that chains together promises, it's like `this` loses meaning after `validateNumber` is executed.

how do I resolve this?

Comment: I suppose you meant `.then(this.generateImage)`?

Comment: No, it looses it's meaning when you pass `generateImage` to `then` without binding it to your instance.

Comment: @Bergi... you are correct. updating now.

Comment: With an ES7 proposal, you would be able to do `.then(::this.generateImage)`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts: Using the term "ES7" to refer to proposals is confusing. If ES6 === ES2015 then ES7 === 2016, i.e. it was released last year.

Answer (score -1):

ES6 introduced a feature called arrow functions. Apart from the syntax being more concise than the conventional `function` syntax, it retains the context of this. Essentially, your code can be changed to the following:

```
var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      console.log(this); // MyClass
      resolve({});
});
```

And you also need to retain the context inside the `then`

```
this.validateNumber()
    .then(() => this.generateImage());
```

Comment: The changes I've suggested work for me

Comment: Ah, I missed off the `()`